# Compile nginx with existing pcre?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, pcre

I always install nginx like this:

```
wget ...nginx...
tar zxvf ...
cd nginx...
./configure --with-pcre=../pcre_source_path
make && make install
```

nginx and pcre will installed to /usr/local/

but now I want to install them to /usr/local/lnmp/, so I try to config nginx like this:

```
./configure --with-pcre=../pcre_source_path --prefix=/usr/local/lnmp/nginx/
```

Then I am confused: where is my pcre installed? I found a /usr/local/share/doc/pcre so I think it's installed to /usr/local/

Then I tried to install pcre independently, so I did this:

```
wget ...pcre
tar zxvf pcre...
cd pcre...
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lnmp/pcre
make && make install
```

with the command above, I installed pcre to `/usr/local/lnmp/pcre/` successfully, but I can't compile nginx with that pcre...(I tried `./configure --with-pcre=/usr/local/lnmp/pcre/`, but it gives me an error, because it must be `--with-pcre=[pcre_source_path]`)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, when compiling nginx against a custom compiled library, such as pcre, zlib and OpenSSL, you must use the options `--with-cc-opt` and `--with-ld-opt`.

In the situation described by you, the `configure` command should be:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lnmp/nginx/ --with-cc-opt="-I /usr/local/lnmp/pcre/include" --with-ld-opt="-L /usr/local/lnmp/pcre/lib"
```

More references: [Nginx forum](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,226907,226907#msg-226907), [Nginx docs (installing)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/install.html).